# Kotlin Script: Import class across directories/packages

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-script

I'm new to Kotlin so forgive me if this is an easy question. I'm writing a kotlin script that I hope will utilize a custom Hashtable implementation to store data from a file. I'm having trouble getting the script to find the HashTable class.
Here is my structure:

```
.
├── scripts
│   ├── kotlin
│   │   ├── [other scripts]
│   │   └── wordcount.kts
│   └── tests
│       └── wc
│           └── smallfile.txt
└── src
    ├── main
    │   └── kotlin
    │       └── dataStructures
    │           └── HashTable.kt
    └── test
```

The script is `wordcount.kts` and the class I'm trying to `import` is in `HashTable.kt`. I tried `import dataStructures.HashTable` and `import kotlin.dataStructures.HashTable` to no avail. I also tried adjusting the PWD (in IntelliJ runtime configuration) to the project directory, also with no luck. How do I import HashTable correctly? Let me know if I can provide any further information!

Answer (score 0):

`import` is used to link to things that are on your classpath, so before you can use that you need to allow the compiler to actually find that HashTable class.

You have a couple of options, I would however recommend to rename `wordcount.kts` to `wordcount.main.kts` (kotlin script requires the executable to be named x.main.kts for most features to work), `HashTable.kt` to `HashTable.kts` and link it with `@file:Import(<path-to-hashtable.kts>)`.

If you can't rename the hashtable you will need to import it either by compiling it to a class file and adding it to the classpath with `kotlinc -script -cp <dir-with-.class> wordcount.main.kts`. Or compile to a jar and link the jar with `@file:DependsOn<path-to-jar>` in the script.

For the reference to all this stuff, look here: https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/scripting-support.md